# CMMotionManager not producing any .deviceMotions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality, cmmotionmanager

Im working on a AR app for my company, and it is working smoothly, except on around one out of ten devices. (all iphone 4 and 4s, 5.1.1+)

When we run this code :

```
CMDeviceMotion *d = motionManager.deviceMotion;

    if (d == nil && motionManager.deviceMotionActive && motionManager != nil) {
        DLog(@"Device motion is active, but no device motion recieved");
    }
```

We get a solid block of "Device motion is active, but no device motion recieved" on some of the devices, but it seems utterly random.

If `motionManager.deviceMotionActive` is true, and the motion manager exists, the .deviceMotion should return a CMDeviceMotion. But it just returns nil.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this ? The check is being run in my

```
- (void)onDisplayLink:(id)sender
```

Comment: The bugged devices can be found among iphone 4 and 4s alike.

Comment: Have you tried checking object memory allocation/deallocation. May be there is the issue. Also check this link: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/103541-cmdevicemotion-flick-gesture.html

Comment: Do you have the same problem when using the block based methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some roaming about, we discovered that this was due to a infrequent hardware/firmware error. The wisest thing was to check for both motionManager.deviceMotion being Nil, and the motionManager.deviceMotionActive being true.

Comment: What a surprise.... Another Apple bug. Sorry to hear it you wasted so much time on it.

Comment: how did you solve this? i am facing the same issue and do not know what to do. i detect it and show a warning. sometimes calibrating sensors with the built in compass app helps, but sometimes not...

Answer (score -2):

Call the

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:someFrame];
```

or

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
```

method to begin updates and periodically access CMDeviceMotion objects by reading the deviceMotion property.